# Genrate two different kernel image on a single compilation in yocto

Tags: linux-kernel, yocto, bsp

Currently, I am working on the Yocto based project.

On the board, we have two processors of the same series. However, we want to have a different kernel configuration and device tree for both processors.

Take an example:
1. Processor X -> defconfig_A and DTB_A
2. Processor X -> defconfig_B and DTB_B

Question: 
1) Is it possible to compile both the kernel (defconfig_A, DTB_A, and defconfig_B, DTB_B) using the single machine with a single command? OR
2) Do I need to set up two different sources for the above kernel only?

Comment: You can use `KERNEL_DEVICETREE` variable to build more than one device tree during the compilation. However, I suggest to define a second machine to compile more than one kernel.

Comment: You probably will want to have slightly different rootfs as well at one point. You might want to have a look at multiconfig, that allows to build for multiple machines and images in one command and possibly have inter-machine/inter-images dependencies. c.f. https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#dev-building-images-for-multiple-targets-using-multiple-configurations